# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

"Я обращаюсь ко всем жителям города: если видите..." Какой знак должен стоять после слова "города"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для постановки двоеточия нет основания, так же как и для запятой. Первое  предложение - это обращение с законченной мыслью. Между двумя предложениями нет причинно-пояснительной связи. Запятая исказит смысл предложения: т.е. получится придаточное условное предложение. ***Я обращаюсь  ко всем жителям города при условии ... далее по тексту.***

> Получается алогичность предложений. Постановка двоеточий была бы возможной, если добавить слово **" просьба''.
> Напр.: Я обращаюсь ко всем жителям города *с просьбой:** ***если видите такие надписи, то уничтожайте их беспощадно, ведь в страшном плену зависимости может оказаться близкий вам человек. Двоеточие как раз указывает, разъясняет, что эта за просьба.***
>   *Поэтому в вашем предложении можно поставить или точку , или ***(лучше) восклицательный знак***. Поскольку предложение содержит некий призыв, просьбу, обращенную к жителям города.*

Comment: Спасибо! Очень доходчиво :)

Answer (score 2):

Постановка двоеточия возможна, как возможны запятая, тире и новое предложение. Ответить нельзя - вопрос неправилен. Нужно приводить контекст, на худой конец - полное предложение.

Comment: Полное предложение: Я обращаюсь ко всем жителям города: если видите такие надписи, то уничтожайте их беспощадно, ведь в страшном плену зависимости может оказаться близкий вам человек.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение можно оставить без изменения, двоеточие имеет изъяснительное значение:

Я обращаюсь ко всем жителям города: если видите такие надписи, то уничтожайте их беспощадно, ведь в страшном плену зависимости может оказаться близкий вам человек.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: "Я обращаюсь ко всем гражданам: необходимо сделать усилие и преодолеть боль и горе".